# Java list stream, get all elements or just one?

Tags: java, recursion, java-8

I have a method that returns an Arraylist of elements.
Sometimes I need the whole list, and sometimes just to check if the resulting list is not empty (just the bool).

Since that method does some heavy tasks to check if something should be added to the result list, is there a way to
break in the method in case it adds one element to list??

I would like to use the same method, but sometimes break if one element is added to the list, and sometimes let it do all work (and add everything else).

I can pass some boolean flags that will indicate if the method should break when there is a first element added event,
but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution (with stream or something...).

I added pseudo code as an example. This method is recursive, and I would like to (optionally) avoid additional recursive calls if I add an element in the first iteration:

```
List<String> getData(argument) {
  List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>;
  ... // do some heavy stuff that produces flag 'shouldAddElement'

  if (shouldAddElement) {
    elements.add('a');
  }

  if (someCondition) {
    elements.addAll(getData(argument));
  }

  return elements;
}
```

Comment: Need the current code to understand your problem

Comment: Can you please explain bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a predicate `shouldContinue` (or even equivalently `shouldStop`) to the method and based on the evaluation of the predicate you can decide to continue/stop.

However, adding this parameter to a public method may not seem that appropriate, so you could create two methods - one that stops after adding one element, and one that keeps continuing (since anyway the caller needs to decide whether to stop after one element or to keep going(if you decide to pass a flag) - so, you may very well have two methods IMO).

```
List<String> getOneElementData(argument) {
    return getDataInternal(argument, elements -> elements.size < 1);
}

//You can even extend the above to take the desired final list size as a parameter
// and have the predicate as elements -> elements.size < desiredSize

List<String> getData(argument) {
      return getDataInternal(argument, elements -> true); //Always keep going
}

private List<String> getDataInternal(argument, Predicate<List<String>> shouldContinue) {
  List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>;
  ... // do some heavy stuff that produces flag 'shouldAddElement'

  if (shouldAddElement) {
    elements.add('a');
  }

  if (someCondition && shouldContinue.test(elements)) {
    elements.addAll(getData(argument));
  }

  return elements;
}
```

Comment: It is a better solution than the the one I posted. +1 (I think the requirement is for `getOneElementData` to return `boolean`)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very elegant. but you can use the fact that list is mutable.
See this simple example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");  list.add("B");  list.add("C");
manipulateList(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

where `manipulateList` is defined by:

```
void manipulateList(List<String> list) {
    list.add("D");
}
```

The printout after the manipulation is:

> [A, B, C, D]

Note that you did **not** use the method return value. It returns void. This way you can get the manipulated List without having your method returning it.
Now make `manipulateList` return a `boolean` which you can use as needed. Something like:

```
boolean manipulateList(List<String> list, boolean stopOnconditionMet) {

    while (...) {//represents the long process

        if(conditionMet && stopOnconditionMet ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

You could also add a convenience method:

```
List<String> manipulateList(List<String> list) {
    manipulateList(list, false);
    return list;
}
```